# Open a new window/tab

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am working on a donations website.  In my page, I have a textbox which accepts a numeric value from the user (that is, money to be donated).

In my code-behind, I have a method which checks whether the value in the textbox is numeric.  The method generates an error message if the number is invalid.

I also have a JavaScript which, after checking that the value in the textbox is numeric, opens a new tab to the website confirmation page, thanking the user for his donation.  Here is the code of the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function Open_Window()
        {
            var textbox = document.getElementById('DonationTextBox');

            if (textbox.value != "")
            {
                if (isNan(textbox) == false)
                {
                    window.open("DonationConfirmation.aspx")
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

The problem is that the tab is NEVER opened, even if the number is valid.  Can you please help me solve this problem?  Thank you.

P.S.

Here is the code of the button that initiates the validation:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="PayPalButton2" runat="server" ImageAlign="Middle" 
                                        ImageUrl="Resources/Icons/PayPalCheckOut.gif" 
                                        onclick="PayPalButton2_Click" OnClientClick="Open_Window()"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Open_Window()
    {
        var textbox = document.getElementById('<%=DonationTextBox.ClientID%>');                        
        if (textbox.value != "" && !isNaN(textbox.value)) {                
             window.open("DonationConfirmation.aspx");
        }
    }
</script>
```

**edit**

 
instead of isNan should be isNaN (javascript is casesensitive)

Comment: I tried your code but the tab still doesn't open.  I can't figure out what's wrong since the code seems correct.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried altering to isNaN but the problem is still there.

Comment: Thank you so much :)))))))))))))))))  It works perfectly now :)  I can not thank you enough :)

Answer (score 3):

The function name is `isNaN`. Note: The final 'N' is capital. That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this line...

```
if (isNan(textbox) == false)
```

be this instead...

```
if (isNan(textbox.value) == false)
```

Comment: I altered the line but the problem still persits :s

Comment: If I remove the validation code from the script and leave the window.open part, it works.

But for some reason, when I introduce those two checks, the tab is never opened.

Comment: can you trying putting a console.log("test"); or alert("test"); at the start of your javascript function to see if anything gets logged or alerted?

Comment: you could also trying console.log(textbox); after the var textbox = document.getElementById('DonationTextBox'); line to ensure you're getting the element correctly

Comment: Where are the logs stored please?  Sorry if this may be a stupid question but I am relatively new to JavaScript.

Comment: what browser are you using? usually hitting F12 should bring up developer tools and you should see a console option

Comment: I'm using Firefox.  I discovered how to open the error console.  Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a stripped down working jsFiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/pjgalbraith/QZeSF/

The html:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="PayPalButton2">Open</a>
<textarea id="donationTextBox">1</textarea>​
```

And the js:

```
function openWindow() {
    if($('#donationTextBox').val() && isNaN($('#donationTextBox').val()) === false)
        window.open("http://www.google.com/", "mywindow");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#PayPalButton2').click(function(){
        openWindow();
    });
});
```

​

Answer (score 1):

First, I would recommend explicitly parsing the number, not relying on the implicit [`ToNumber`](http://es5.github.com/#x9.3) operation that will be applied when you pass a string into `isNaN`. Presumably your users are inputting decimal, so if it's meant to be a whole number (e.g., 10), use:

```
var num = parseInt(textbox.value, 10);
```

If it's meant to be a number with a fractional component (e.g., 10.5), use:

```
var num = parseFloat(textbox.value);
```

You probably want `parseFloat` for a currency value.

Then your `if` condition becomes `isNaN` (note that the final `N` is capped) on `num`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function Open_Window()
        {
            var textbox = document.getElementById('DonationTextBox');
            var num = parseInt(textbox.value, 10);

            if (!isNaN(num))
            {
                window.open("DonationConfirmation.aspx")
            }
        }
</script>
```

And lastly, are you sure that the client-side ID of the textbox really is 'DonationTextBox'? ASP auto-generates client-side IDs, you may need to use [`ClientID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) instead, e.g.:

```
var textbox = document.getElementById('<%=DonationTextBox.ClientID%>');
```